# How to display an element as a block with text in it?

Tags: html, css

style.css:

```
.bar75 { display:block; text-indent:-9999px; width:75px; background-color: rgba(184,201,204,1.00);}

.bar100 { display:block; text-indent:-9999px; width:375px; background-color: rgba(184,201,204,1.00);}
```

index.html:

```
 <td width="100%"><span class="bar100">.</span></td>
```

How it looks is

[image]

I want it to be displayed with the text inside. Like "Advanced" written in it. I tried

```
<td width="100%"><span class="bar100">Advanced</span></td>
```

It doesn't display the text. Where should I place the text?

Comment: remove text-indent:-9999px; from the css

Comment: Why did you even add the `text-indent`? Do you know what it is for?

Comment: I didn't. Downloaded a template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer - Remove `text-indent:-9999px;`. This is removing the text :)

Comment: Why is this in a table?

Comment: Where is it supposed to be? Answer'll be accepted in 5 mins.

Comment: It's hard to tell from the information I have in your question. Can you add all your HTML / CSS to a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)? I'd be interested to see it.